# Manipulating elements on the page with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, console

Is it possible to write a javascript script clicking a button on a webpage that is not embedded in html?
It is written in javascript and implemented using script src.

Comment: Hey, I can tell you that it's not only possible, but that it's also pretty common. It's good practice to show us what you've tried so the people answering your questions know where to start helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to click a button that was created dynamically on the page, as long as the creation of the button come before your script.

For example, a button created like that:

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerHTML = 'newButton';
button.id = 'buttonId';
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(button);
button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    alert('Button clicked');
});
```

Can be accessed by your script with this code:

```
document.querySelector('#buttonId').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, then the button is not present in the HTML markup initially, but is added to the markup using javascript?
In this case, you need to write your script, which will be executed after the button is added, and everything will work.